# Modificar registro CRUD tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, crud

Espero pueda alguien darme una mano con esto. Estoy creando una interfaz la cual se pueda introducir datos que serán guardados en Sql. Este CRUD tiene la posibilidad, de agregar un dato nuevo (pozos), eliminarlo y modificarlos.
La única que no funciona es Modificar el registro, esta en la función llamada 'actualizar2'...siempre que se acciona el botón 'Modificar registro' la funcion va directo al except y su mensaje de advertencia y no pasa por el try.
Pueden tomar el script y ejecutarlo para que puedan ver lo que les comento si desean
Espero que alguien pueda darme una mano con esto
Gracias

```
> ventana2=Tk() df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\NmbrUsr\Desktop\Carpeta1\PozosTipo.txt', header=0)
>ventana2.geometry("620x550")
> nombreColumnas=df1.columns.values 
>nombreColumnas=list(nombreColumnas)
> nombreColumnas.insert(0,'*Seleccione Pozo Tipo*') 
> miID2=StringVar()
> miPozo2=StringVar() 
> miFechaPEM=StringVar() miPozoTipo=StringVar()
> miPozoTipo.set(nombreColumnas[0]) 
> miFactor=IntVar() 
> miFactor.set(1)
> miComentario=StringVar()
> def conexionBaseDato2():
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
> 
>     try:
>         miCursor.execute('''
>             CREATE TABLE pozos_nuevos (
>             ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>             Pozo2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>             FechaPEM DATE NOT NULL,
>             PozoTipo INT NOT NULL,
>             Factor INT NOT NULL,
>             Comentario VARCHAR(20))
>             ''')
>         messagebox.showinfo("CONEXION","Base de datos creada exitosamente")
>     except:
>         messagebox.showinfo("CONEXION","Conexión exitosa con la base de datos")
> 
> def eliminarBaseDato2():
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
>     if messagebox.askquestion(message="Los datos se perderán definitivamente, ¿Desea Continuar?",title="ADVERTENCIA"):
>         miCursor.execute("DROP TABLE pozos_nuevos ")
>     else:
>         pass
> 
> def limpiarCampos2():
>     miID2.set("")
>     miPozo2.set("")
>     miFechaPEM.set("")
>     miPozoTipo.set("")
>     miFactor.set(1)
>     miComentario.set("")
> 
> def mensaje2():
>     acerca='''
>     Agregar info necesaria para pozos nuevos
>     '''
>     messagebox.showinfo(title="INFORMACIÓN", message=acerca)
> 
>  ########### Métodos #############
> 
> def crear2():
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
> 
>     comentario=miComentario.get()
>     if comentario=='Agregue comentario' or comentario=='':
>           comentario='Sin comentario'
>     else:
>         comentario=miComentario.get()
> 
> 
>     try:
>         datos= miPozo2.get(), miFechaPEM.get(),miPozoTipo.get(),miFactor.get(), comentario
>         miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO pozos_nuevos VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?)",(datos))
>         miConexion.commit()
>     except:
>         messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","Ocurrió un error al crear el registro, verifique conexión con base de datos")
>         pass
>     limpiarCampos2()
>     mostrar2() def mostrar2():
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
>     registros=tree2.get_children()
>     for elemento in registros:
>         tree2.delete(elemento)
>     try:
>         miCursor.execute("SELECT*FROM pozos_nuevos")
>         for row in miCursor:
>             tree2.insert("",0,text=row[0],values=(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]))
>     except:
>         pass
> 
> #############TABLA2##############
> 
> tree2=ttk.Treeview(ventana2,height=15,columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3','#4'))
> tree2.place(x=2,y=160) tree2.column('#0',width=50)
> tree2.heading('#0',text="ID",anchor=CENTER)
> tree2.heading('#1',text="Pozo",anchor=CENTER)
> tree2.column('#1',width=150) tree2.heading('#2',text="Fecha de
> PEM",anchor=CENTER) tree2.column('#2',width=140)
> tree2.heading('#3',text="Pozo Tipo",anchor=CENTER)
> tree2.column('#3',width=150)
> tree2.heading('#4',text="Factor",anchor=CENTER)
> tree2.column('#4',width=80)
> tree2.heading('#5',text="Comentario",anchor=CENTER)
> tree2.column('#5',width=320)
> 
> 
> def seleccionarUsandoClick2(event):
>     item=tree2.identify('item',event.x,event.y)
>     miID2.set(tree2.item(item,"text"))
>     miPozo2.set(tree2.item(item,"values")[0])
>     miFechaPEM.set(tree2.item(item,"values")[1])
>     miPozoTipo.set(tree2.item(item,"values")[2])
>     miFactor.set(tree2.item(item,"values")[3])
>     miComentario.set(tree2.item(item,"values")[4]) tree2.bind("<Double-1>",seleccionarUsandoClick2)
> 
> def actualizar2(): #error en el try linea miCursor
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
>     try:           
>      datos=miPozo2.get(),miFechaPEM.get(),miPozoTipo.get(),miFactor.get(),miComentario.get()
>         miCursor.execute("UPDATE pozos_nuevos SET Pozo2=?, FechaPEM=?, PozoTipo=?, Factor=?, Comentario=? WHERE ID="+miID2.get(),(datos))
>         miConexion.commit()
>     except:
>         messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","Ocurrió un error al actualizar el registro")
>         pass
>     limpiarCampos2()
>     mostrar2()
> 
> def borrar2():
>     miConexion=sqlite3.connect("BasePozosNuevos")
>     miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
>     try:
>         if messagebox.askyesno(message="¿Realmente desea eliminar el registro?",title="ADVERTENCIA"):
>             miCursor.execute("DELETE FROM pozos_nuevos WHERE ID="+miID2.get())
>             miConexion.commit()
>     except:
>          messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA","Ocurrió un error al tratar de eliminar el registro")
>          pass
>     limpiarCampos2()
>     mostrar2()
> 
> #############
> ############# --- Ventana Pozos Tipo
> #############
> 
> def VerRegistroPT():
>         df1.index.name='Dia'
>         root=Tk()
>         root.title("Pozos Tipo")
>         root.geometry("700x440")
> 
>         table = Text(root)
>         table.insert(INSERT, df1.to_string())
>         table.pack()
>         scrolly = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, command=table.yview, width=14)
>         scrolly.place(in_=table, relx=1, relheight=1, bordermode="outside")
>         
>         table.config(bg="#5E91CD", border=3, fg="#FDFEFE", state="normal",
>                      relief=tkinter.FLAT, yscrollcommand=scrolly.set, undo=True
>                      )
>         root.mainloop()
> 
> def CrearRegistroPT():
>     NmbrPT=StringVar()
>     root=Toplevel()
>     root.title("Carga de Pozos Tipo")
>     root.geometry("350x460")
>     lpt=Label(root,text="Nombre Pozo Tipo")
>     lpt.place(x=10,y=10)
>     lmnj=Label(root,text="*Pegue la columna de valores \n sin el encabezado*")
>     lmnj.place(x=10,y=420)
>     lmnj.configure(font=("Arial", 8, "italic"))
>     ept=Entry(root,textvariable=NmbrPT, width=30)
>     ept.place(x=140,y=10)
>     table = Text(root)
>     table.place(x=10,y=40)
>     table.configure(height=23,width=40)
>     scrollh = tkinter.Scrollbar(root,command=table.xview, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
>     scrollh.place( in_=table, )
>     scrollv = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, command=table.yview, width=14)
>     scrollv.place(in_=table, relx=1, relheight=1, bordermode="outside")
>     table.config(bg="#5E91CD", border=3, fg="#FDFEFE", state="normal",
>                      relief=tkinter.FLAT, yscrollcommand=scrollv.set,xscrollcommand=scrollh.set, undo=True
>                      )
> 
>     #scrollh.config(command=table.xview)
>     def tomarDato():
>             mi_variable = table.get(1.0, 'end')
>             df2=mi_variable.split('\n')
>             df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)         
>             df2.columns=[ept.get()]
>             df3=df1.join(df2)
>             df3.to_csv(r'C:\Users\t01hkruteler\Desktop\Prono Producción Py\PozosTipo.txt', index=False)
>             bGuardar.configure(bg="#87F96D", text='Cargado', fg='#851F0B')
>     bGuardar=Button(root, text="Cargar",fg='#25468B',width=10,command=tomarDato)
>     bGuardar.place(x=260,y=420)
>     root.mainloop()
> 
> def ventanaPozosTipo():
>     ventanaPT=Toplevel()
>     ventanaPT.title("Pozos Tipo")
>     ventanaPT.geometry("160x100")
>     bVer=Button(ventanaPT, text="Ver Registro Pozos Tipo  ",bg='#FDEBD0',command=VerRegistroPT)
>     bVer.place(x=10,y=10)
>     bCargar=Button(ventanaPT, text="Cargar Nuevo Pozo Tipo",bg='#F5CBA7',command=CrearRegistroPT)
>     bCargar.place(x=10,y=40)
>     ventanaPT.mainloop()
> ########## Creando etiquetas y cajas de texto #################
> 
> e12=Entry(ventana2,textvariable=miID2)
> 
> l22=Label(ventana2,text="Pozo",bg="#D6DADD") l22.place(x=50,y=10)
> e22=Entry(ventana2,textvariable=miPozo2, width=30)
> e22.place(x=180,y=10)
> 
> l32=Label(ventana2,text="Fecha de PEM",bg="#D6DADD")
> l32.place(x=50,y=40) e32=DateEntry(ventana2,textvariable=miFechaPEM)
> e32.place(x=180,y=40)
> 
> l42=Label(ventana2,text="Pozo Tipo",bg="#D6DADD")
> l42.place(x=380,y=40)
> e42=ttk.Combobox(ventana2,textvariable=miPozoTipo)
> e42['values']=nombreColumnas e42.place(x=450,y=40)
> 
> l52=Label(ventana2,text="Factor de conversión",bg="#D6DADD")
> l52.place(x=50,y=70) e52=Entry(ventana2,textvariable=miFactor,
> width=10) e52.place(x=180,y=70)
> 
> e62=Entry(ventana2, textvariable=miComentario, width=35)
> e62.place(x=375,y=70, height=30) e62.insert(0, "Agregue comentario",)
> e62.configure(font=("Arial", 8, "italic"))
> ############ Creando botones ##########
> 
> b12=Button(ventana2, text="Crear Registro",bg="#ABEBC6",
> command=crear2) b12.place(x=50,y=120) b22=Button(ventana2,
> text="Modificar Registro", command=actualizar2) b22.place(x=180,y=120)
> b32=Button(ventana2, text="Mostrar Lista", command=mostrar2)
> b32.place(x=320,y=120) b42=Button(ventana2, text="Eliminar Registro",
> bg="#F1948A",command=borrar2) b42.place(x=450,y=120)
> 
> bPT=Button(ventana2, text="Ver/Cargar Pozo
> Tipo",bg='#FDEBD0',command=ventanaPozosTipo) bPT.place(x=465,y=10)
> 
> ventana2.mainloop()
```

Comment: No puedo hacer pruebas con el código que pusiste. Tuve que hacerle una modificación. Estaría bueno que corrijas el código mostrado para que no se tenga que hacer esas modificaciones. Más allá de eso, no puedo avanzar más con las pruebas por que no tengo el csv. Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar un csv de muestra por favor? (no es necesario que sea con datos reales, es solo para pruebas)

Comment: Ya que comenté, te quería decir otra cosa. Eso de que salta al except ocurre cuando el código dentro del try da un error del tipo que aclares en la linea del except (que son todos si no se aclara). En este caso tu except captura todos los errores. Prueba el código de la función actualizar2 quitando el try-except y verás el mensaje de error verdadero.

Comment: Hola Dante, gracias por responder. No encuentro cómo subir un archivo. El txt es una tabla de dos columnas con encabezado y el nro de filas q quieras, basicamente es una matriz y es indistinto su tamaño.
Probé scarle el try para haer el intento, me aparece como error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Fecha PEM
Cambie todo lo que involucra 'Fecha PEM' a 'Fecha_PEM' para eliminar espacios y el error cambia a: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Fecha_PEM

Comment: No hace falta subir el txt (ni se puede). No lo subas en otra pagina, si el link a dicha pagina se cae la pregunta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores. Simplemente pegalo en la pregunta y dale formato de código. Esto se hace seleccionandolo todo y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto.

Comment: Encontré el error, luego de eliminar los espacios, eliminé la base de datos y la volví a crear, ahí pudo identificar el nuevo nombre de columna.
Me sirvió mucho tu aporte de sacar el try y except para ver claramente el error. Gracias